# R - sort() output missing a row

Tags: r, sorting, rows, missing-data

I have `A` and `B` as follows:
//edit// I was sleepy and confused. These are NOT data frames.

```
> length(A)
[1] 490
> length(B)
[1] 17730

> str(A)
 num [1:490] 0.0113 -0.0106 0.2308 0.0435 0.2814 ...
> str(B)
 num [1:17730] 0.0118 0.0196 0.0344 0.0207 0.0566 ...
```

But for some reason when I used `sort()`:

```
> length(sort(A))
[1] 490
> length(sort(B))
[1] 17729        #should be 17730
```

I don't know how to produce a reproducible example in this particular case, and I'm stuck on how I should go about troubleshooting this. What should I check?

Comment: Are you using `nrow` or `NROW`? This is very weird!

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I'm using `nrow()`

Comment: Hmm.. I am really confused. I don't understand how either `sort` or `nrow` is working on `A` and `B` which you claim are data.frames; let alone figuring out why you are losing a row. I should shut up.

Comment: post `str` of A and B

Comment: So sorry. It was not a data frame so not `nrow()` but `length()` I'll remember to get some sleep before posting here, not the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed out that `sort()` takes a vector and not a `data.frame`, but are there any NAs in the vector? The default in `sort()` is to remove NAs:

```
v <- c(2, 1, NA)
v
#[1]  2  1 NA

length(sort(v))
#[1] 2
length(sort(v, na.last = T))
#[1] 3
```

If you want to sort a data.frame you should use `order()` instead of `sort()`. `order()` has the same `na.last` argument as `sort()` except the default is `TRUE` instead of `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(vars = c(2, 1, NA))
df_n <- data.frame(df[order(df$vars),])

nrow(df_n)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: `> length(sort(B, na.last=T)) [1] 17730` that is correct! Now I just need to figure out why there was an NA there in the first place. Thank you and sorry for the confusion between `nrow()` and `length()`